# min-height percentages cannot be nested

Tags: html, css

```css
#background {
  background-color: #F00;
  height: 100px;
}

#outer {
  background-color: #0f0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#inner {
  background-color: #00F;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the `#outer` div has the full height of 100px, but the `#inner` div has a height of 0px.  Why can min-height percentages not be nested?

Tested on Firefox and Chromium

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952791/nested-min-height-not-working-when-both-are-percentages) asks about the same thing but there's no explanation of why this is expected behavior.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  The accepted answer to that question says "This is a reported bug" and the bug it links to is marked as `[RESOLVED FIXED]`.

Comment: read the answer more carefully.  In a nutshell- this isn't a "bug", this is the expected behavior given the way minimum height is calculated.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense.

Comment: See my answer in the duplicate for a complete explanation.